# Flume Hive Sink Error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, flume

I am generating data to a spool directory  and redirecting that to a hive table using flume hive sink. Flume sink is connected with hive metastore but after that I am facing the following issue.

Issue

> :Unable to deliver event. Exception follows org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1

Flume.conf

```
flume-hive-ingest.sources = src1
flume-hive-ingest.channels = chan1
flume-hive-ingest.sinks = sink1

flume-hive-ingest.sources.src1.type = spooldir
flume-hive-ingest.sources.src1.channels = chan1
flume-hive-ingest.sources.src1.spoolDir = 
/vagrant/flume_log

flume-hive-ingest.channels.chan1.type = memory
flume-hive-ingest.channels.chan1.capacity = 1000
flume-hive-ingest.channels.chan1.transactionCapacity = 
1000

flume-hive-ingest.sinks.sink1.type = hive
flume-hive-ingest.sinks.sink1.channel = chan1

flume-hive-ingest.sinks.sink1.hive.metastore = 
thirft ://one.hdp:9083
flume-hive-ingest.sinks.sink1.hive.database = default
flume-hive-ingest.sinks.sink1.hive.table = stocks

flume-hive-ingest.sinks.sink1.serializer = delimited
flume-hive-ingest.sinks.sink1.serializer.delimiter = ,
flume-hive-ingest.sinks.sink1.serializer.fieldnames = 
date ,open,high,low,close,volume,adj_close
```

Hive script

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stocks;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE stocks (
date STRING,
open DOUBLE,
high DOUBLE,
low DOUBLE,
close DOUBLE,
volume BIGINT,
adj_close DOUBLE)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION '/ingest/stocks';
```

Comment: `date` is a reserved word in Hive. Are you sure that table was created okay?

Comment: Yupp. The table was created successfully..